# Postman Mock Server Response Body

Tags: json, header, postman

I created a mock server using Postman, then I accessed the server url, I got **HTML response body**. However, I want **JSON response body**.

What do I have to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's JSON but the content type header isn't set in the example response section. You need to add the `Content-Type`:`application/json` header.

Comment: thanks, but I could't get json response.

Comment: Can you update the question with an image of the example where you have included that header in the response section.

Answer (score 9):

To get the correctly formatted response, you need to include the `Content-Type` header in the *response* section of the `Example`.

This is what the Mock Server response looks like without the header:

[image: Without Content-Type header]

Open the `Example` and add the header to the bottom response section, you may see the `Body` tab shown when you open the `Example`, switch tabs to `Headers`, add the header and save the `Example`.

[image: Adding the Header]

With the header added, send the request to the Mock Server, this will return the correctly formatted response based on the `Content-Type` header.

[image: With the Content-Type header]

Comment: this was helpful, i was setting the application/json on the top of the page, but it should be set on the bottom on the response side and not the request side